# WPF How do you set the Background color of a context menu so that it overrides the background color of a grid

Tags: wpf

I have a style set as follows:

```
<Style TargetType="Grid" >
        <Setter Property="Control.Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <SolidColorBrush>
                    <SolidColorBrush.Color>
                        <Color A="255" R="51" G="50" B="51"/>
                    </SolidColorBrush.Color>
                </SolidColorBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter> 
    </Style>
```

I then have a style set for a context menu that looks like this:

```
    <Style x:Key="contextMenuItem" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}" >  
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink" /> 
    </Style>
```

The context menu appears on a StackPanel nested within the grid.  I don't understand why but the background for the context menu is always Darkgray outlined in Pink.  The only way to get the Context Menu to display properly is to disable the style for the grid.  I've tried everything I can think of including creating a ControlTemplate for ContextMenu.

Why is the grid background color affecting the menu background color and how on earth do I make it knock it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
<Style TargetType="Grid" >
```

you are defining the style for **all** `Grid` controls in your application (if you have defined the style in App.xaml) or window (if you have defined the style in the Window's resources). Or if you have defined this Style using `<Grid.Style>`, then it will apply to all `Grid`s in the visual tree below the styled `Grid`.

Since the default `MenuItem` control template also contains a `Grid` control, it also will be styled exactly like all your other `Grid`s.

In order to avoid that, you should better use

```
<Style x:Key="myGridStyle" TargetType="Grid" >
```

and use `Style="{StaticResource myGridStyle}"` for those `Grid`s that you want to style with this particular color.

Comment: You sir are a scholar and a gentleman.  I didn't realize it rendered a grid in the context menu by default, nor did I realize how far down that style was pushing.